# Fb share button to share data inside one div using django

Tags: django, facebook

I want a fb share button to share a particular data on a webpage to fb using django.I found options to share data to fb,but they are sharing the whole url to fb, i want to share some data not the whole page.
Is there any django app to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Each share needs an individual page(id find the url but im on mobile right now but that is a requirement specified by facebook). That being said, once they have their own urls you CAN include them all in the same page or div.